# Batch text editing .rtfd files

Tags: macos, text, batch-processing, editing

So I have a large bunch of .rtfd text files also containing images. What I'd like to do is making the following edits to all of these files:

1. Delete everything before a certain line of text, which I'll call 'start_line' here.
2. Delete every line that says 'a_line'.
3. Delete everything starting from (and including) 'end_line'.

So if the **input files** look like this:

> line1
>
> line2
>
> start_line
>
> line3
>
> a_line
>
> line4
>
> end_line
>
> line5

I want the **output files** to look like this:

> start_line
>
> line3
>
> line4

Please note that the output file does not include end_line, but it does still include start_line.

Also the output files must remain in the **.rtfd format** and retain all **images**, as well as their original **lay-out**.

I am using Mac OSX and do not have much experience with batch text editing. Can this be done using the terminal? Or can you point me to a piece of software that allows operations like this?

Thank you very much!

**Edit: The lines I specified earlier can also just be seen as strings of text, so the input file would become:**

> text1
>
> start_string
>
> text2
>
> unwanted_string
>
> text3
>
> end_string
>
> text4

So the output would be:

> start_string
>
> text2
>
> text3

Comment: Have you tried anthing?

Comment: That's a pretty tall order! Have you looked inside an `rtfd` file? It is a massive mess of markup and there is no one-to-one correlation between what you call `lines` in your input document and the `lines` in an `rtfd` file since lines there may contain formatting information and may span multiple lines so if you remove a line in the `rtfd` file, it may remove half of some formatting information too... don't hold your breathe!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So you think that it is not possible to do this? I've tried using Automator to edit these files but did not achieve the desired results... I still hope to find a solution though. Perhaps I did not express myself very well, because the **lines** I told you about may not actually be lines in the document as you said, but if we just look at them as **strings**, would it be possible to do this then? So deleting everything that comes before a particular string, after another (thereby also deleting this 'ending string' and also deleting every instance of a third string?

Comment: I edited my question above, I hope this clarifies my problem! The text must no longer be seen as being on a particular line, just as parts of text coming before or after certain strings.